# How to add data from my SQL database to a table in my Webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a website where I need to populate data from my Database into a table designed in my `Dashboard.aspx` page.

I have designed the table like this:

```
<div class="card">
          <div class="card-header border-transparent">
            <h3 class="card-title">Devices</h3>

            <div class="card-tools">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse">
                <i class="fas fa-minus"></i>
              </button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="remove">
                <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body p-0">
            <div class="table-responsive" id="devices" runat="server">
              <table class="table m-0">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Host</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Status</th>
                  <th>Description</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <!-- Insert Data From SQL Database -->
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <!-- Insert Data From SQL Database -->
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <!-- Insert Data From SQL Database -->
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <!-- Insert Data From SQL Database -->
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <!-- Insert Data From SQL Database -->
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <!-- Insert Data From SQL Database -->
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <!-- Insert Data From SQL Database -->
                </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Okay so now where it says `<!-- Insert Data From SQL Database -->` needs to be the data from the database table.  I know that it would have to be dynamically created each row in the table.  And this is where I don't know how to achieve it.   I did some research and mostly are using `GridViews` but I need to display it in the table above.

I have given the table an ID and `runat="server"` but from here I am not sure what line of code to use to populate the data?

Thanks

Comment: All ASP.NET tutorials show this - you don't put any code in the HTML. You load the data in the code-behind, add a `foreach` loop in the ASPX file to iterate over the results and add the proper ASP.NET tags to emit specific properties.  A `GridView` is a control that does all the looping and rendering automatically, emitting a `<table>` and `<tr>` tags just like your code does.

Comment: On the other hand, why mix the dinosaurian WebForms with Bootstrap? That's *exactly* why WebForms were abandoned. There's just no easy way to combine ASPX controls with modern classes and styles. Sure, you can use `CssClass` to emit classes, but WebForms will emit a ton of its own HTML as well. WebForms was never ported to ASP.NET Core either, which means your code is *already* obsolete as you write it.

Comment: GridViews create tables automatically so you don't have to write it out. Use a gridview with a datasource control. The previous comment is somewhat true but also very exaggerated.